# Efficient Hessian-Laplace blob detector implementation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, local-features

As it is mentioned in a paper for [SURF](ftp://ftp.vision.ee.ethz.ch/publications/articles/eth_biwi_00517.pdf), it is possible to approximate hessian determinant using integral images.

If I want to implement Hessian-Laplace detector, is it feasible to also approximate Laplacian of Gaussian with the same approach?

Basically, I want to use the fast determinant of Hessian from SURF and while computing it, also get the laplacian by taking the trace of Hessian.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can [approximate Gaussian Blur by Box Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49583) which can be calculated by Integral Image.

From that you can do [Difference of Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) which is an approximation of the Laplacian of Gaussian.

Usually I'd just use different method to accelerate those calculations.
For instance, see [recursive implementation of the Gaussian Blur](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22075). It has [some extensions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55440) among them even gradients.