# Recursive Implementation of the Gaussian Filter (1D & 2D)

Tags: image-processing, matlab, filters, filter-design, software-implementation

I'm trying to implement an IIR form to approximate the Gaussian Blur Filter.
I'm working with the article "[Recursive Implementation of the Gaussian Filter](http://homepage.tudelft.nl/e3q6n/publications/1995/SP95TYLV/SP95TYLV.pdf)" by Ian T. Young and Lucas J. van Vliet.

They suggest a form and way to calculate the coefficients as given by:

[image]

I'm trying to reproduce their example for $ q = 5.0 $.

There is the MATLAB code I wrote:

```
qFactor = 5;

b0Coeff = 1.57825 + (2.44413 * qFactor) + (1.4281 * qFactor * qFactor) + (0.422205 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor);
b1Coeff = (2.44413 * qFactor) + (2.85619 * qFactor * qFactor) + (1.26661 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor);
b2Coeff = (-1.4281 * qFactor * qFactor) + (-1.26661 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor);
b3Coeff = 0.422205 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor;

normalizationCoeff = 1 - ((b1Coeff + b2Coeff + b3Coeff) / b0Coeff);

vDenCoeff = [b0Coeff, b1Coeff, b2Coeff, b3Coeff] / b0Coeff;


vXSignal = zeros(61, 1);
vXSignal(31) = 10;

vYSignal = filter(normalizationCoeff, vDenCoeff, vXSignal);
vYSignal = filter(normalizationCoeff, vDenCoeff, vYSignal(end:-1:1));

figure();
plot(vYSignal);
```

Now, the result I get is this:

[image]

Namely, I get a filter which isn't stable.
Yet it seems I get the same coefficients as they get in their example.

What am I missing?
Has anyone ever implemented this method?

Thank You.

Comment: i've never had the occasion of implementing a gaussain filter other than as an FIR on a big table of data.  normally, the only time i am implementing an IIR filter is for a real-time application and i have never done a gaussian filter in that context.  but i have read about them (at least in an analog filter textbook). i dunno how to do an all-pole gaussian, but i imagine that there is a way to approximate it for analog filter. then it depends on if the time-domain or frequency-domain performance is more important to you whether you choose impulse-invariant or bilinear transform to convert it.

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49583.

Comment: Related to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50576.

Comment: Here is Lucas van Vliet’s original C code, written for that paper. It has been modified over the years to fit into the DIPlib library, and then to work in a C++ compiler, but the core of the code is mostly the same. https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/master/src/linear/gaussiir.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was simple, the article uses the coefficients value on one hand where the MATLAB implementation on the other.
Namely, a minus sign should be added.

Here's the correct code:

```
qFactor = 5;

b0Coeff = 1.57825 + (2.44413 * qFactor) + (1.4281 * qFactor * qFactor) + (0.422205 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor);
b1Coeff = (2.44413 * qFactor) + (2.85619 * qFactor * qFactor) + (1.26661 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor);
b2Coeff = (-1.4281 * qFactor * qFactor) + (-1.26661 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor);
b3Coeff = 0.422205 * qFactor * qFactor * qFactor;

normalizationCoeff = 1 - ((b1Coeff + b2Coeff + b3Coeff) / b0Coeff);

vDenCoeff = [b0Coeff, -b1Coeff, -b2Coeff, -b3Coeff] / b0Coeff;


vXSignal = zeros(61, 1);
vXSignal(31) = 10;

vYSignal = filter(normalizationCoeff, vDenCoeff, vXSignal);
vYSignal = filter(normalizationCoeff, vDenCoeff, vYSignal(end:-1:1));

figure();
plot(vYSignal);
```

Comment: It is really nice of you to post a question and get back to share you self developed answer.