# Fastest Available Algorithm to Blur an Image (Low Pass Filter)

Tags: image-processing, optimization, software-implementation, blur, performance

I am working with a camera that produces ugly artifacts:
[image]

by using ANY blur filter on the camera's output the visual quality improves drastically:
[image]

The above image was created using OpenCV's [cv::medianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) with a kernel size of 3.
I identified [cv::medianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga564869aa33e58769b4469101aac458f9) to be the fastest smooth/blur method in OpenCV.
However for my needs it is still too slow since it uses up to 80% of the whole processing time including encoding (ffmpeg MPEG4). I already tryed to use [cv::UMAT](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html) but uploading each Image to the GPU and downloading the result again is taking even more time. So using OpenCL / Cuda isn't an option either!?

Therefore I am looking for the fastest way to blur/smooth an image. However there are so many algorithms in so many libraries(OpenCV/IPP/swscale) to implement and test them all would take to much time. So do you have any suggestions which algorithms I can take a look at, or could offer a really good performance?

Here are some test results for 75.000 iterations of a 640x360 image:

```
+------------------------------+--------+----------+
|          Algorithm           | Kernel | Time(ms) |
+------------------------------+--------+----------+
| cv::medianBlur               | 3x3    | 18492    |
| cv::medianBlur ocl           | 3x3    | 54596    |
| ippiFilterMedianCross_8u_C3R | 3x3    | 15755    |
| cv::blur                     | 3x3    | >100000  |
| cv::GaussianBlur             | 3x3    | >100000  |
| cv::filter2d                 | 3x3    | >100000  |
+------------------------------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: these artifacts look like JPEG compression was overdone. There's a load of papers on reducing JPEG artifacts – I'd recommend googling for something like "JPEG artifact reduction OpenCV"

Comment: oh, and the idea with GPU computing is always that you hide the copy overhead by a) copying up a whole bunch of images and computing over them at once b) already copying over the next bunch while the current is still being processed and starting the next computation before copying down the results of the previous one. Pipelining!

Comment: And: is 640x360 really your target image size, or are you aiming for larger images?

Comment: Yes this is true, but the camera streams the video as MJPEG, therefore I have no infulence on the compression just decompression. To remove the artifacts there might be a lot of great algorithms, but they are even slower than a simple blur.

Comment: My hypothesis is that running on your GPU, your memory bandwidth will become the limit, and you can apply relatively complex repair algorithms. The problem is just that your images are so small that the whole overhead per image is large. Put them in a three-dimensional array and copy over 75,000 of them at once!

Comment: (hint: GPUs real-time blur whole HD screen contents while also rendering them, at pretty high rates, so yes, that's possible: your pictures would be small even for textures on models in 3D games)

Comment: The GPU compute Idea seems really interesting gonna test it. And report back my findings.

Comment: by the way, how hard would it be to run your benchmark with at 75.000 different images (or at least different copies of the same image in RAM) instead of the same image? Point being that CPU cache logic is really good at keeping small portions of data local, i.e. starting from your second iteration over the same image, there's no data transfer from RAM into the CPU happening anymore (unless something goes horribly wrong); that'd possibly skew your results a bit!

Comment: Iam using a video as source so the all images are different. To isolate the blur performance Iam using a Profilier. The profiler is working correcly I double checked the values using a high precision timer.

Comment: so, these are 75000 different images that you ran the benchmark over? Then, all is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest blur would be Box Blur.
You can implement it using [Running Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).
I think Intel [`FilterBoxBorder`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-filterboxborder) works in that manner.

If you'd like you can do a few passes of it to approximate the Gaussian Blur.

You can also use IIR Filter Coefficients to blur the image quite easily.

You may have a look at my project [Fast Gaussian Blur](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/FastGuassianBlur).

Comment: Is there any existing optimized implementation for Box Blur? For me it looks like it could use some SSE instructions and cache optimization. There is also the method `ippiFilterBox` "https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-filterbox" which is around 2 times slower than the ippiFilterMedianCross.

Comment: Pay attention that you don't compare apples to apples. The Median Filter is working on 8 / 16 Bit images. The Box Blur works on 64 Float. Try [`FilterBoxBorder`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-filterboxborder) on the same image type and it should be faster.

Comment: I used `ippiFilterBoxBorder_8u_CR3` for my test. and recyceld the buffer. That was 2 times as slow `ippiFilterMedianCross`

Comment: @Royi raises an interesting point: what's the image data type you get as input? Generally, convolution with a 3×3 kernel should be "pretty fast" in the sense of "a reasonable algorithm will have memory bandwidth as bottleneck", and that means that the smallest data type that represents your image makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Input Format is RGB888 / CV_8UC3 / 8u_CR3

Comment: It seems something is awkward about this. Running Sum should require less operation than median even with the tricks for median known for Discrete Image values (8 / 16 Bit). Which version of IPP do you use? Could you share the code on IPP forum? It seems you might found an issue here.

Comment: My code uses some references to ffmpeg and opencv but it is pretty much this example code: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/586160

Comment: Which version of IPP? You really should let them know about your findings. Anyhow, the IIR Option or the Running Sum options are the fastest. Nothing can beat that.

Comment: Newest Version: 2018 Update 3

Comment: After doing some more tests I noticed that `ippiFilterBoxBorder_8u_CR3` takes a dynamic mask size, while `ippiFilterMedianCross_8u_CR3` is using a fixed mask size of 3x3 or 5x5. I think that might explain the performance difference. However if I have time I will post my findings in the Intel forums.

Comment: @Crigges, I really doubt that's the reason.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a fast 5x5 Gaussian-blur in C++ and compared the performance to OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3B+ running 32bit Raspbian OS. The function uses all the 4 cores of the Raspberry Pi and works 2-3 times faster than OpenCV. The boost is even more on 64bit OS. Here is the link to code with documentation:
https://github.com/zanazakaryaie/fastGaussianBlur

Comment: Does your implementation support any size of Gaussian Blur?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I needed a 5x5 kernel back then

Comment: It makes sense to say something about it on your post.